# Non-homogeneous differential equation - nomenclature

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to translate into English the abbreviation of the following general formula:

> General Solution of the Non-homogeneous Differential Equation =
>   General Solution of the Homogeneous Differential Equation + Special
>   Solution of the Non-homogeneous Differential Equation

Is in English language the following abbreviation (or any other) used?

> GSNHDE=GSHDE+SSNHDE

Comment: I know the abbreviation DE or ODE is used. Do you really need to write all of this as abbreviations?

Comment: Those abbreviations do look like a thing. For good reason, I may add, because I am fairly certain that we could verify experimentally that an achronym of six letters either composes a readable word, or it is more akin to "cryptography" than it is to an "abbreviation".

Comment: Yes, I do. I have to write the abbreviation just below the solution of an equation and there is certainly no place for the whole sentence.

Comment: I would choose a shorter abbreviation.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is, wether it is commonly used. I wouldn't like to create a new abbreviation for what already has one.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read this type of abbreviation type  in  standard ODE books. However the general solution of  Non-homogeneous ODE can be written in the form

> $$y=y_c+y_p$$
>   where $y_c$ is solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation and $y_p$ is solution of non-homogeneous part of the ODE, which are also known as complementary function and particular integral respectivly.